# Erros when i tried to include js libraries via requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I tried to include some **js** libraries like bootstrap, jQuery.ui etc... via **requirejs** method but, I encountered some errors

Here is the console errors :

> ```
> Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-storageapi
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> Error: Load timeout for modules: jquery.bootstrap
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
>
> Error: Script error for: jquery.bootstrap
> ```

**Nb:** for the `Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-storageapi`error refer to the line `require.js:166:17` and this line 166 is:

```
/**
     * Constructs an error with a pointer to an URL with more information.
     * @param {String} id the error ID that maps to an ID on a web page.
     * @param {String} message human readable error.
     * @param {Error} [err] the original error, if there is one.
     *
     * @returns {Error}
     */
    function makeError(id, msg, err, requireModules) {
        var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
        e.requireType = id;
        e.requireModules = requireModules;
        if (err) {
            e.originalError = err;
        }
        return e;
    }

    if (typeof define !== 'undefined') {
        //If a define is already in play via another AMD loader,
        //do not overwrite.
        return;
    }

    if (typeof requirejs !== 'undefined') {
        if (isFunction(requirejs)) {
            //Do not overwrite and existing requirejs instance.
            return;
        }
        cfg = requirejs;
        requirejs = undefined;
    }
```

My **requirejs-config.js** :

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "jquery.bootstrap": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min",
        "jquery.3": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min",
        "jquery.ui": "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery.3': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery.ui': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Then I call my fonction like this **exemple** :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery.3'], function (jQuery, jQuery3) {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('.js-toggle-menu').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.mobile-header-nav').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDNhe.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You've read the mentioned urls and acted accordingly? I don't see any relevant informations the mentioned links would produce...

Comment: *"Load timeout for modules"* - looks like you're getting a timeout...

Comment: @Andreas what do you mean by the mentioned urls ? where i can find them ?

Comment: The URLs in the console (and your first blockquote)...

Comment: @freedomn-m i tried also to set waitSeconds : 30, but nothing happen

Comment: @Andreas look please my screenshot

Comment: Now there are URLs in your console, in the first blockquote and in your screenshot. Did you follow and read them? They are there for a reason.

Comment: Yes i see, load failure this file: `jquery/jquery-storageapi.js `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration does not make any sense and indeed it should not work. In `paths` you have this association

```
"jquery.3": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min",
```

And then in your `shim` you have:

```
'jquery.3': {
  'deps': ['jquery']
},
```

That makes no sense at all. The file you get from `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min` *is* jQuery, but you are setting a `shim` that says that jQuery is dependent on... jQuery. What??

At a minimum, you'd need to fix that problem, and use something like this:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "jquery.bootstrap": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min",
        "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min",
        "jquery.ui": "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.ui': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Besides fixing the configuration for jQuery, I've also removed the `shim` for Bootstrap. Bootstrap 3 required a `shim`. Bootstrap 4 detects whether an AMD loader is present and calls `define` to register itself as a proper module.

Note that you'll also need to download [`popper`](https://popper.js.org/) and make it available to RequireJS so that Bootstrap can work because Bootstrap 4 lists it among its dependencies. If you run into issues getting `popper` to work, please search this site because it's been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brequirejs%5D+bootstrap+popper) quite a bit already.

I would also call Boostrap `bootstrap` rather than `jquery.bootstrap` but that's a matter of preference more than anything.

Comment: Thank you @Louis for your explanation, i updated my code but i have already the errors ! `Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-storageapi`, `http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror`, `Error: Script error for: jquery.3` `require.js:166:17` please look my post for the line 166 details

Comment: as your exemple if i have to call some function thats depends to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min` i have to call it like this: `requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery'], function (jQuery) { myfunction()... });` ?

Comment: I reduce the errors, now I have just this one `Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-storageapi
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror` always line 166 of require.js:166:17